# laravel route parameter to controller and returning JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-routing

If I have a route in Laravel

```
Route::post('/user/{user}/project/{project}/git-add', 'GitController@stageFiles');
```

How do I access the user and project variables from the controller function being called?

Also, do I need to specify that I am returning a JSON object in the routes file, or is that all taken care of in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For following route:

```
Route::post('/user/{user}/project/{project}/git-add', 'GitController@stageFiles');
```

You need to create `stageFiles` method in `GitController` and from your `stageFiles` method:

```
public function stageFiles($user, $project)
{
    // $user && $project both are available in this method as parameters
}
```

Comment: So the method suggested by Antonio is not correct? Also, do you mean "for your stagefiles method"?

So do the parameters in the controller method need to be the same name as they have in the routes?

Comment: @user231416, Names could be anything but order has to be maintained. BTW, you made a comment `Just what I needed, thanks a lot.` how ?

Comment: I don't have any way to test yet, I just thought it was what I needed.

Comment: Ok, I marked it as correct. I was confused because I do know for a fact I need to use the
`var = Input::get("name")` at another point in my program.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you access them:

```
$user = Input::get('user');
$project = Input::get('project');
```

And Laravel will understand your json just fine.

Comment: @user231416 If you find your question's answer, you would have to set it as an answer by clicking the correct sign on the left of it.